# Wicket: FileUpload delete with RepeatingView

Tags: java, file-upload, wicket

Following [Wicket: FileUploadField with ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604516/wicket-fileuploadfield-with-listview) now I need to allow the user to delete the files one by one with a button next to the FileUploadField.

It works properly when the files were already saved, but when they weren't the FileUploadField is reseted...

So I have tried this:

```
AjaxLink<Void> deleteLink = new AjaxLink<Void>("deleteLink") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {     
                EtdConfigForm parent = (EtdConfigForm)EtdDokumentRowForm.this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
                EtdDokumentRowPanel panel = (EtdDokumentRowPanel)EtdDokumentRowForm.this.getParent();
                parent.removeDokument(panel);
                target.prependJavascript("var itemRemove = document.getElementById('"+ panel.getMarkupId() + "');" +
                        "itemRemove.parentNode.removeChild(itemRemove);" + 
                        "Wicket.$('" + panel.getParent().getParent().getMarkupId() + "').children('"+ panel.getMarkupId()+"').remove();");
                target.addComponent(parent);
            }
        };
        add(deleteLink);
```

But it doesn't work... I mean the ajax piece... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should avoid such chainy invocations of the method, based on current component's location, cause it is not flexible at all.

To find typed parent component you could use component's `findParent(final Class<Z> c)` method.

Actually, I can't understand where your `AjaxLink` is placed, but I think it should be directly at `EtdDokumentRowPanel` closely to `FileUploadField`.

So, to remove whole `EtdDokumentRowPanel` you should remove it from `RepeatingView` first and execute script with markup deletion then. Of course, if you stored this panel somewhere else (in `EtdConfigForm`, I suppose), then it should be deleted from there too.

Not to search for `RepeatingView` in parent objects, you better transfer it to each `EtdDokumentRowPanel` via constructor.

It will be something like that:

```java
public class EtdDokumentRowPanel extends Panel
{
    ...
    public EtdDokumentRowPanel ( String id, EtdDokument doc, final RepeatingView view )
    {
        //your panel should have markup id:
        setOutputMarkupId ( true );
        ...
        AjaxLink<Void> deleteLink = new AjaxLink<Void> ( "deleteLink" )
        {    
            @Override
            public void onClick ( AjaxRequestTarget target )
            {
                EtdDokumentRowPanel thisPanel = EtdDokumentRowPanel.this;

                // removing row panel from RepeatingView:
                view.remove (thisPanel);

                // execute this js to remove child from Wicket parent component:
                target.prependJavascript ( 
                        "Wicket.$('" + view.getParent ().getMarkupId () + "')" +
                        ".removeChild(Wicket.$('" + thisPanel.getMarkupId () +
                        "'));" );    
            }
        };
        add ( deleteLink );
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the button is in the row panel. Many many thanks for your kind help.